# Create copy of a document in CosmosDB SQL API before updating it

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In Cosmos DB with SQL API, I need to make a copy of a JSON document from backend(USP with JavaScript code) before new version of same document is overwritten by API. This Copy needs to have its property tag 'Latest' to 'false'

1. Tried to create an SP which creates a copy of the document before updating but I am unable to create the copy of document as error is thrown saying getBody() method is anonymous
2. Tried to create a pretrigger which creates copy of document but trigger wasn't getting kicked off as I am running the code on Azure Portal
3. I can use getBody() in UDF or separate USP but they cannot be called from inside my base USP as it is not allowed

```
function ChangeDocument(AId) {
var context = getContext();
var coll = context.getCollection();
var link = coll.getSelfLink();
var response = context.getResponse();
var doc = getContext().getRequest().getBody();
var ts = new Date();
var time = ts.getTime().toString();
var idNew = doc.id + time;
var oldDoc = docs[0]
var historyDoc = {
    "id": idNew,
    "Content": oldDoc.Content
};
coll.createDocument(link, historyDoc, function (err, docCreated) {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error('Error: ' + err.message);
    }
});
doc.AuditFields.Latest = false;
var replace = coll.replaceDocument(doc._self, doc, {},
    function (err, newdoc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        response.setBody(newdoc);
    });
if (!replace) {
    throw new Error('The document could not be updated.');
}
}
```

My aim is to

1. JavaScript to create Copy of old document with flexibility to modify properties
2. Update the document using a stored procedure by running this from Azure portal
3. I will be elevating this code to do bulk import/updates eventually